# Logging out User from one System if logged in another System

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, logging

I have a web application where user first log in to view the pages. My task on which I am is stuck is as follows.

If User is logged in from System A and does not log out, and he then logs in from System B, how can I make sure that the User is logged out from System A when he log ins from System B?

What adjustments do I have to made in my Data Base. I have log table which keep the records when user log in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just log his IP address when he logs in - if the current IP is different from the stored IP, log him out of the stored ID.

Comment: That assumes that their IP is static - possibly a safe assumption on a small intranet, almost certainly not on the internet. We don't know which of those is the OPs situation (or which is closer to their situation)

Comment: With the miniscule amount of information offered, this seemed a viable strategy.  Other solutions offered (sessionID, GUID) are also viable.  I note too that the OP hasn't queried/offered opinions on any suggestion :(

Comment: I'd say the IP approach is too error prone, considering the alternative and the work involved with that. OP, might as well need security that you aren't working on the same data in two place at once, even on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling much about the structure. But I guess you have a "User" table.

In there you could have a Session ID, and if that changes, then you have logged in, in another place. So if you are logged in to "System A", you get a SessionID, which you check up against every call or every now and then.

Then you log into "System B", a new Session ID is created, and applied to the User table.

"System A" will then at some point look it up, and see that it is not the same as the one it knows about, and tells the user to log in again, or just simply forces a log out.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I can think of will be -

1) After a user successfully logins, system creates a Guid and saves it inside user's SessionState as well as in user's table.

2) When the user requests a page, compare the user's SessionState value with the one from user's table.

3) If not same, redirect to Login page.